# OpenEdge BREAK-BY QTY and Sum of rows

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have an orderline table which has QTY field and I would like to group items the way it is shown in image.

[image]

I tried using this:

```
FOR EACH RobotOrderline NO-LOCK
    BREAK BY RobotOrderline.OrderedQty.
        DISPLAY RobotOrderline.OrderedQty.
END.
```

But even the grouping seems wrong.

[image]

Comment: The break by doesn't actually group the results (although it does sort), but allows you to use the FIRST-OF and LAST-OF functions. If you want Progress to do summing for you, you need to look at the "ACCUMULATE" clauses which will then allow you to do the sum, and display when 'LAST OF'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually sum the quantities. Also the for each still runs for each row in the table, it only orders them and sets flag for different locations in the order (first, last, first-of, last-of).

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iQty AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

FOR EACH RobotOrderline NO-LOCK
    BREAK BY RobotOrderline.OrderedQty.
    iQty = iQty + RobotOrderline.OrderedQty.
    IF LAST-OF(RobotOrderline.OrderedQty) THEN DO:
        DISPLAY RobotOrderline.OrderedQty iQty.
        iQty = 0.
    END.
END.
```

Comment: What's the difference between THEN and THEN DO:?

Comment: DO: starts a block that ends with END.

Comment: If I put a FOR EACH block inside of DO, and the FOR EACH is iterating a table, does it iterate it completely or only one time?

Comment: That shouldnt really matter. A for each will iterate all records unless you stop it with a leave or return etc